# issues using htmlspecialchars($_POST['']) to keep data on value after submitting

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I am using `htmlspecialchars($_POST[''])` to keep the data submitted with errors on my registration form,

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ;?> ">
    <div>Company</div>
    <input type="text" name="user_account" size="20"
        value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_account']); ?>" 
        placeholder="Company Name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

but before the page is submitted, I am getting unknown data where I am using the `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_account'])`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try this <?php echo isset($_POST['user_account']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_account']) : ''; ?>

Comment: If it's before the page is submitted, do you mean that you expect the `htmlspecialchars` function to apply to what the user enters immediately?

Comment: when u dont submit form u $_POST['user_account'] is empty .

Comment: No GeoffAtkins, because before htmlspecialschars with input value is suppose to be empty, but doesn't it. thanks

Comment: Please define "unknown data" (show an example of the output).

Comment: I am calling "unknown data" because dont know the data is comming from on my form, Im getting "<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  user_account in <b>/va..."  instead empty or the "placeholder=" info.

Comment: @user1229266 — That's an error message because the index of POST you were trying to access doesn't exist.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)